# Is it a good Idea to use a Game Structure Coding Style to build a simple system?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

Yes, as what I'm trying to think is that, for example I want to create a simple library system. but my question is it is a good idea to use a game structured system using rendering? Would it give give a performance issue? Also, since I want that system to be compatible with few operating system using libGDX.

Comment: I don't think a library system requires anything a game development framework offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a game structured system for making a GUI for simple software is not a good idea, because it will consume a lot of time, you can use Java in netbeans for simple softwares it has a drag and drop menu where many components needed for software are present you can use them by just draging and droping them where you needed.

Using a game structured system can give software a non-traditional look, But if you are really good at that game structured system then you can make a very stylish GUI, but it will be non-traditional.

Comment: Does the performance won't drop from using it?

Comment: As far as performance is concerned, I think game structured systems are build by keeping in mind that they have to show good performance, because a good game will consume a lot of CPU resources. But I can't say anything exact about the performance, because it will completely depend on the code which is written behind the built in funcitons of that game structured system.